# How to have flashing background and text on li's with query

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-cycle

Im trying to create a flashing background and text effect where each li is assigned a class color for background and text. First dialog id link visible and li being hidden until the link is clicked. I've downloaded the jquery cycle plugin onto my server and set up my html/css but I'm having trouble with hiding the li's and getting the cycle to start.

Current CSS:

```
ul li { list-style: none; }

.black { background-color: #000; }
.yellow { background-color: #FFFF00; }
.white { background-color: #FFF; }
.green { background-color: #7CFC00; }
.blue { background-color: #00FFFF; }
.pink { background-color: #FF00CC; }
.orange { background-color: #FF8C00; }

#visible-words {
    text-align: center; font-size: 100px;
}
```

Currently html:

```
<body>
    <div id="overlay">
        <div id="dialog">
            <h1><a href="">Contains flashing images</a>.</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="words-wrap">
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <ul id="visible-words">
        <li class="black"><span class="yellow">Flash</span></li>
        <li class="yellow"><span class="black">Flash</span></li>
        <li class="black"><span class="yellow">Flash</span></li>
        <li class="yellow"><span class="black">Flash</span></li>

        <li class="black"><span class="white">Text</span></li>
        <li class="white"><span class="black">Text</span></li>
        <li class="black"><span class="white">Text</span></li>
        <li class="white"><span class="black">Text</span></li>

        <li class="black"><span class="green">Flash</span></li>
        <li class="green"><span class="black">Flash</span></li>
        <li class="black"><span class="green">Flash</span></li>
        <li class="green"><span class="black">Flash</span></li>

        <li class="black"><span class="white">Text</span></li>
        <li class="white"><span class="black">Text</span></li>
        <li class="black"><span class="white">Text</span></li>
        <li class="white"><span class="black">Text</span></li>

        <li class="black"><span class="blue">Flash</span></li>
        <li class="blue"><span class="black">Flash</span></li>
        <li class="black"><span class="blue">Flash</span></li>
        <li class="blue"><span class="black">Flash</span></li>

        <li class="black"><span class="white">Text</span></li>
        <li class="white"><span class="black">Text</span></li>
        <li class="black"><span class="white">Text</span></li>
        <li class="white"><span class="black">Text</span></li>

        <li class="black"><span class="pink">Flash</span></li>
        <li class="pink"><span class="black">Flash</span></li>
        <li class="black"><span class="pink">Flash</span></li>
        <li class="pink"><span class="black">Flash</span></li>
</ul>
```

I've done a search for similar topics but none of which seem to achieve the effect of what I was looking for using list items with a background color. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: But why do you hate photosensitive epileptics so much..? Though, in all honesty, while that was a (poor) joke, it's worth noting that flashing text/background-colours are not often considered 'good,' or 'useful,' design decisions.

Comment: @DavidThomas lol Thanks for note. I am aware that it wouldn't be considered a 'good' design decision. However, this is simply for a Halloween themed page animation. While it won't be up very long I am still interested in finding out how to achieve the effect :)

Comment: What code have you tried? Can you post a jsFiddle?

Comment: Well, you could always [just use CSS animations](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tUg4A/).

Comment: @DavidThomas I suggest posting that as an answer before I steal it.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks, David. I wasn't aware of keyframes rule in the CSS animations. Did a bit more reading and experimenting on it. This should work for what I am looking for in my animation effect. Appreciate the help.